# nodejs mongoose, callback, compare old data and storing new data to variable

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io

After retrieving data from database, I would like to compare the old against the new, and then store the new into the variable oldData. I have trouble storing it into the oldData. Am I writing it correctly regarding the scope? It does not seem to be able to store it to oldData. Could you help?
Thanks.

```
const myDB = require('./dbModel/model');

let oldData = {}
const getApiAndEmit = (socket) => {
  try {

    // Get the latest data point
    const res = myDB.find()
     .limit(1)
     .sort({created_at: 'desc'})
     .then((response)=>{
        const newData = response[0]

        if (oldData != newData) {
          // Send update to clients
          io.sockets.emit('Update', response )
          // Store new data
          oldData = newData

        } else {
          // do nothing
        }
      })

   .catch((err)=>{
     console.log(err);
   })

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.code}`);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (odlData != newData) {
```

1. This looks like a typo (odlData -> oldData).
2. You can't compare objects like this. Use lodash.isEqual() or something comparable.

Comment: the problem I am having seems to be I have no access to oldData inside the callback (after .then). Am I writing it correctly regarding the scope?